# Proof of Lipschitz continuous

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Wikipedia says that an everywhere differentiable function g : R → R is Lipschitz continuous (with K = sup |g′(x)|) if it has bounded first derivative. How to prove that?

Comment: Hint: Mean Value Theorem

Comment: Mean Value Theorem requires function to be continous on interval [a, b] but I only know that f is differentiable and f' is bounded.

Comment: Consider what differentiability might tell you about continuity.:)

Comment: ...and what continuity in a *closed, bounded* interval might tell you.

Comment: Differentiable implies continuous. If $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ exists then $\lim_{h\to 0} (f(x+h)-f(x))=0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews give him a moment to think about it for himself.:)